# Yii extension for admin panel creation

Tags: php, yii

I need to create admin site, currently I'm using Yii Framework, but the problem is that I have a huge DB with a lot of tables in it, and relations between them. It would be a hell setting all of them by standard Yii methods. Is there a good extension for Yii that can help me reduce time of coding?

Comment: can you not use gii? The only problem may come if you have composite primary keys in any of your tables, as I don't think gii supports them.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/giix/

Comment: I got the same question several days ago. Did you try the Backvendor? www.yiiframework.com/extension/backvendor/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There area having many extension for this

you can check following extension for this

[ycm](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ycm/)

[qtzpanel](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/qtzpanel/)

and

[yii-user-management](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user-management/)

I thing it solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can give this one a try: http://www.gxccms.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try FullModel and FullCrud from [gii-template-collection](https://github.com/schmunk42/gii-template-collection).

If you have eg. MySQL Inno DB Tables, relations are generated automatically into the models. And the CRUD also can show and update your related tables, use the "slim" templates.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting my blog post here to help those who want to create their own admin panel in Yii framework.

Here I tell you complete steps to **[separate front and admin panel in yii framework](http://scriptbaker.com/how-to-separate-front-and-admin-panel-in-yii-framework/)**.